# internet explorer 11 doesn't recognize null in localstorage getitem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

```
if (localStorage.getItem("userTotal") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('userTotal', 3700);
}
```

This if statement checks if storage with a name of userTotal is empty (null),  then if it is we assign a value of 3700. I looked in internet explorer 11 console and it gives me this error "Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference". What could be the problem.

Comment: I see, thank you for reply.

Comment: I was wrong IE8 and later do have localStorage - perhaps you're running in IE7 mode - IE does tend to randomly switch to degraded mode for no reason at all - check what emulation mode you're in

Comment: I'm running on IE11

Comment: IE11 is the problem.

Comment: yes, I know ... and IE11 has this wonder *feature* that lets you emulate it's doddering predecessors ... check to see which mode you're in - if you don't know how to do that, just console.log(navigator.userAgent

Comment: @emix - IE8,9,10,11 had localStorage, IE11 is **NOT** the problem - unless it's emulating IE7 or earlier

Comment: @Bravo,  it gave me this undefined "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Comment: I'm doing all of this so my project would be compatible with all of the browsers, now im just thinking if I should ditch it with ie

Comment: hmm, that's IE11 mode - why does it not have localStorage

Comment: Are you loading a page using `file:///` protocol? that won't have localStorage ... has to be http or https

Comment: I tried on both file:// and http://, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Oh, it started working on http now! Thank you.